# How to access attribute elements from a JSON file in Django Template?

Tags: python, django

I am parsing a JSON file that is located remotely and which gets updated constantly with new data. I am not going to write the whole structure of the JSON file, cause it would be too much.  So far I can get and display names and images on the template, it is straightforward, but what I don't know is how to access some elements with an **attribute** and with a **leading underscore**.

Let see part of the JSON file:

```
[{ 'searchResult' : [{'@count': '5',

'item': [{ 

           'itemId': ['352565431707'],

           'title': ['Smart Tab ST8200 Quad-core 7" HD Tablet Android 8.1 Oreo 8GB'],

           'galleryURL': ['http://thumbs4.flickr.com/m/maf6ZygaFcxqMsVv2DQTh6g/140.jpg'],

           'sellingStatus': [{'currentPrice': [{'@currencyId': 'USD', '__value__': '49.0'}],

           'itemURL': ['http://rover.somewebsite.com?item=352565431707']}]

'item': [{ 

       'itemId': ['352565431808'],

       'title': ['iPhone 11 latest phone '],

       'galleryURL': ['http://thumbs4.flickr.com/m/maf6ZygaFcxqMsVv2DQOm6g/140.jpg'],

       'sellingStatus': [{'currentPrice': [{'@currencyId': 'USD', '__value__': '1200.0'}],

       'itemURL': ['http://rover.somewebsite.com?item=352565431808']}]
```

This is part of my code in **views.py**

```
    url = 'http://svcs.somewebsite.com?RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=JSON&keyword=something'
    r =  requests.get(url).json()

    search =r['searchResult'][0]['item']

    context = { 'items': search }
    template='home.html'
    return render(request, template, context)
```

This is part of my code in **home.html** template

```
{% for item in items %}
  <a href = "{‌{ item.itemURL.0 }} />             
    <img src="{‌{ item.galleryURL.0 }}" alt="{‌{ item.title.0 }}" />
  </a>
  <h2>{‌{ item.title.0 }}</h2> 
  <h3>{‌{ item.sellingStatus.0.currentPrice.0.__value__.0 }}</h3>                           
{% endfor %}
```

According to what I have it renders the image and the title, but when I try to access the **__value__**, because of the leading underscore I get an error message, and honestly I don't know if I am accessing the attribute properly with this approach.  Back to my question, **How can I access the attribute in this particular case and how can escape the leading underscore ?**   Thank you so much in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I love to share what I know with the world here is the answer to my own question. After doing some research and scratching my head for days,  I came up with this solution, that works great for my case.

In order to access the attribute elements and the leading underscore, I had to clean up the data in views and do the iteration in views as well. I created four variable-containers that i would use to append every result of that iteration. If you don't do this, you will end up getting only the last result of the iteration in the template.

Answer (score 1):

Friend, you have to use the same variable declared in FOR loop. You must use item variable instead of items. Technically items does not exist in that area:

```
{% for item in items %}

   <a href="{{item .viewItemURL.0}}">    
     <img src="{{ item .galleryURL.0 }}" alt="{{ item .title.0 }}" />
   </a>
   <p>Names: {{ item .title.0 }}</p> 

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you for responding to my question. That is actually the way I had it. For some reasons I typed “list” instead of “item”. Now is fixed. As I said before it works well and does what I want but still don’t know how to access the attribute element and especially when it has a leading underscore.

Answer (score 0):

Friend, did you manage to solve the problem?
If not, a possible easier solution would be using javascript.
Try to somehow store the tag variable {{items}} in a javascript variable.

```
for (let item in variableItems){
    let currentPrice = variableItems[item].sellingStatus[0].currentPrice[0];
    console.log(currentPrice['@currencyId'];
    console.log(currentPrice['__value__'];
}
```

and once done this use the values ​​for the purpose you want.

---

Another possible solution would be in the backend to remove the @ character and the __ (since the @ character generates problems in the template). You can use the replace function. `str.replace('@', '')`  and str.replace('__' , '')

y en la pantilla html:

```
{{ item.sellingStatus.0.currentPrice.0.currencyId}}

{{ item.sellingStatus.0.currentPrice.0.value}}
```

Comment: Hola friend! If you take a look at my approach (see context on views.py) in order to iterate through the list of elements on the template, your suggestion is not possible or maybe I am wrong. If you can give me an example how to do this on views.py that would help me a lot more. Thank you!

Comment: Hola José, how would access the attribute element in the template, based on my question?  Thank you!